# Not able to pull windows container images on docker on windows 10

Tags: docker, containers

I am new to docker. I have successfully installed docker desktop on windows 10 machine. I switched to windows containers from docker settings. I am not able to pull any windows containers' images on my machine. It is showing error messages as follows: -

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1
```

It is giving error

```
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

Similarly it is giving error for

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1709
1709: Pulling from windows/nanoserver
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

However I am able to successfully pull the linux container images.

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           18.09.2
API version:       1.39
Go version:        go1.10.8
Git commit:        6247962
Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version:          18.09.2
API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
Go version:       go1.10.6
Git commit:       6247962
Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:28:48 2019
OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
Experimental:     true
```

I have also set the Experimental option to true.

I am behind proxy but I have set my proxy credentials in the settings of docker daemon.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I strongly doubt something wrong when you switch to windows mode, restart your docker service & check again if it's really in windows container mode.

Comment: I have done this several times but no improvement.